# Sm.regression in R doesn't work

Tags: r, regression

I have a problem with my code in R. I'm trying to predict a value using the previous one. Every method works fine except for the Local Regression.
My csv file is this:
[CSV file](https://mega.co.nz/#!w1R0yRja!Z4C4ZD6GpVzrZNtaudF6jx19N8w_jdw73dA3BNRGdws)
My code is this (it may be bad, but it's not important, at least for now):

```
attach(dataset1)
f=c(Fish)
f=as.integer(f)
#My new dataset. I must predict a value using the previous one
fish=data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(f)-2, ncol = 2))
names(fish)=c("A1", "A")
supp=c(1:length(f))
for (k in 2:length(f)-1)
{
    fish$A1[supp[k]-1]=f[k]
}
for (k in 3:length(f))
{
    fish$A[supp[k]-2]=f[k]
}
#Local regression
library(sm)
rand=sample(1:length(f)-2, length(f)/2)
s=fish[rand,]
v=fish[-rand,]
val=matrix(NA, 150,1)
#I try to find the best h to use
for(i in 1:150)
{
h=i/100
sm1=sm.regression(s$A1,s$A, h=h, add=F, ngrid=500)
val[i]=(sum(v$A-sm1$estimate)^2)
}  
best=which.min(val)/100
plot(fish$A1, fish$A)
sm.regression(s$A1,s$A, h=best, add=T, ngrid=500)
```

I don't understand why i'm not getting a graphic (i just get some points). If i insert an array like `1:length(f)-2` as the x, the final `sm.regression` works fine.

Comment: I don't know if it's what is causing problems but note that `2:length(f)-1` probably isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: It should probably be `2:(length(f)-1)`

Comment: that's not the problem in my case. Even if i do that, the regression doen't work.